# JQuery animating based on variable attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have multiple divs with the same class name that we would like to animate based on their given attribute values:

```
<div class="chart-bar"  style="width:10%;" bar-width="100%"></div>
<div class="chart-bar"  style="width:10%;" bar-width="70%"></div>
<div class="chart-bar"  style="width:10%;" bar-width="30%"></div>
```

When we attempt:

```
$(".chart-bar").animate({width: "60%"});
```

then this works fine (all divs are extended to 60%).
However, when we try:

```
$(".chart-bar").animate({width: $(this).attr('bar-width')});
```

then nothing happens. I'm thinking that perhaps $(this) doesn't work in this context, but I'm currently out of ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: i guess you gots 2 loop thru them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Way 1:**

Using `$(".chart-bar").each(function(){` loop through all the divs with class `.chart-bar` and get the attribute value.

Please check below snippet.

```js
$(".chart-bar").each(function(){
  $(this).animate({width: $(this).attr('bar-width')});  
});
```

```css
.chart-bar{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart-bar"  style="width:10%;" bar-width="100%">Div-1</div>
<div class="chart-bar"  style="width:10%;" bar-width="70%">Div-2</div>
<div class="chart-bar"  style="width:10%;" bar-width="30%">Div-3</div>
```

**Way 2:**

Use `$( ".chart-bar" ).attr( "bar-width", function( i, val ) {` to get attribute for all the div and animate.

Please check below snippet.

```js
$( ".chart-bar" ).attr( "bar-width", function( i, val ) {
  $(this).animate({width: val});  
});
```

```css
.chart-bar{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart-bar"  style="width:10%;" bar-width="100%">Div-1</div>
<div class="chart-bar"  style="width:10%;" bar-width="70%">Div-2</div>
<div class="chart-bar"  style="width:10%;" bar-width="30%">Div-3</div>
```

Comment: Ok - so it needs looping. Great, thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Happy that helped you. Yeah and you can achieve it two way using .each and .attr as mentioned in answer.

Comment: @user1051849 please accept answer so it can help other needed one as well.

Comment: apologies - your answer was so quick that SO wouldn't let me accept it yet. now done. thanks again.